# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while starting tomcat 7 from Ant

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

My goal is to start tomcat using Ant. Here is my script:

```
<target name="tomcat-start">
    <java jar="${tomcat.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" fork="true" dir="${tomcat.home}">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/bin">
                <include name="bootstrap.jar"/>
                <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>

        <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${tomcat.home}"/>

    </java>
</target>
```

After script execution I receive this output:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" 
Java Result: 1
```

**I've checked**: `org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory` class is presented in `tomcat-juli.jar`!

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the classpath entry is pointing at the right spot? You have the jar listed, but you haven't shown where you're storing it, and Ant might not be looking in the right directory for it.

Comment: @chrylis, I've checked file paths using `<echo>` and also have tried different approaches of setting classpath in `<java>` ant task. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some unknown weird reasons tomcat doesn't start in my system even when I launch it from command line using `java -jar` command.

However, I **managed to start** it using `java -cp "bin\bootstrap.jar;bin\tomcat-juli.jar" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap` command, executed from `tomcat.home` directory.

The code in ant which does the same:

```
<exec executable="java" dir="${tomcat.home}">
    <arg line="-cp bin\bootstrap.jar;bin\tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    <arg value="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: I had the exact SAME problem, thank goodness for your response. I spent several hours trying different things found by google-ing. Your solution worked perfectly. I wrapped the `<exec .../>` in a `<target.../>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with using catalina, the proper method is to add \setenv.bat with contents like:

```
set CLASSPATH=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
```

I discovered that by reading catalina.bat. Someone might want to update this with the proper Tomcat doc

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `startup.sh` batch file or shell script of tomcat. It has bunch of other files apart from `bootstrap.jar`. check `setclasspath.sh`. It has all jars are being set in class path.

Other **more clean** approach would be to invoke `startup.sh` script from ant. This will do everything for what it takes to start Tomcat Server.

Comment: I'm using tomcat 7 on windows, and it contains only `bootstrap.jar`, `tomcat-juli.jar`, `Tomcat7.exe` and `Tomcat7w.exe` in `bin` directory