# Getting Tomcat 404 error upon running my WAR file

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting "The requested resource is not available." message upon deploying my war in Tomcat 7.

Here are the details.

1] Name of WAR = devMonitor-1.war

2] **web.xml** as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>main</display-name>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>main.java</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

3] My Jersey RS class

```java
*package main.java;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
**@Path("/hello")**
public class Hello {
    // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }
    // This method is called if XML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }
    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>" + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }
    }*
```

4] URL I am trying to hit = localhost:8080/main/rest/hello

5] POM file if it is of any matter as follows

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.travelport.soa.svcs.pos.uapi.devMonitor</groupId>
    <artifactId>devMonitor</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

6] My tomcat monitor shows app running as follows but still not able to run it.

```
Path        Version     Display Name        Running     Sessions

/devMonitor-1   None specified  main            true        0
```

Comment: true 0 means application is not accessible . When your application will be successfully running then it will be true 1 , so try to re-deploy the application.

Comment: The uri is localhost:8080/devMonitor-1/rest/hello

Comment: I redeployed but still sessions keep showing as 0. What should I do?

Comment: @MauricePerry localhost:8080/devMonitor-1/rest/hello does not work either. Also should the display name in web.xml not play a part in the URL? e.g. http://localhost:8080/devMonitor-1/main/rest/hello

Comment: No. Besides, your tomcat monitor clearly shows that its on /devMonitor-1

Answer (score 0):

Few things be aware of when deploying a WAR file.

TRY:

Redeploy the WAR file from the command line or manager app. Be patient. If your WAR file is large, this could take quite a few minutes. Watch a task manager and see how much CPU Tomcat is using. If it is using 90% or more, chances are the deployment process is not done. 

If the redeploy does not work, stop tomcat, delete the WAR file, place a fresh WAR file in web application folder, restart Tomcat and wait until the deployment process is complete.

Comment: My WAR is just 3 MB. Deploy in Tomcat 7, it does not show any error. Still nothing happens. :(

Log except

Apr 18, 2014 10:50:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
.
.
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Apr 18, 2014 10:50:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\devMonitor-1.war
.
.
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 18, 2014 10:50:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
.
.
INFO: Server startup in 1923 ms

Comment: How are you compiling your WAR file? Are you using an IDE or a more manual process to package the web application?

Comment: I am using Maven POM file to build the war file.

Comment: And running as Maven Install via Eclipse

Comment: And you have no errors in any of the files in the Tomcat logs?

Comment: I am seeing this:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
 .
 .

Comment: [Check this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536532/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-while-starting-tomcat-7-from-ant)